# Python: check if every element in a list exists a specific time

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I have the following question. I have a list of ranges like this:

```
parameterRanges2 = [(1,5),(1,5),(1,7),(1,7),(0,10),(1,20),(1,3),(0,1)]
```

And I have a numpy array like this :

```
arr = np.array([[2.0,4.0,3.0,5.0,1.0,3.0,2.0,4.0,2.0,4.0,3.0,5.0,1.0,3.0,2.0,4.0,2.0,4.0,3.0,5.0],
[4.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,2.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,4.0,1.0,3.0,4.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,1.0,3.0,4.0,2.0],
[2.0,3.0,4.0,6.0,7.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,6.0,1.0,2.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0],
[6.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0],
[8.0,9.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0],
[11.0,13.0,14.0,16.0,17.0,19.0,1.0,3.0,4.0,6.0,7.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,13.0,14.0,16.0,17.0,19.0,1.0],
[1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0],
[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]])
```

Every parameterRange tuple in the list corresponds with the subarray in the numpy array. Is there a way to check if all elements in the corresponding range exists at least one time? so for example that in the first sublist in the numpy array all numbers 1,2,3,4,5 exists at least one time, in the second sublists exists one time and in the third list for example the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 exists one time and so on.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exploiting that the ranges are integer we can give an O(nm) solution, nxm being the shape of `arr`. The algo works as follows:

- discard all non-int elements and all that are outside their range
- use `np.add.at` to efficiently (O(mn)) generate bincounts for in-range numbers
- count the above threshold bins in each row and compare to the range

.

```
import numpy as np

parameterRanges2 = np.array([(1,5),(1,5),(1,7),(1,7),(0,10),(1,20),(1,3),(0,1)])

arr = np.array([[2.0,4.0,3.0,5.0,1.0,3.0,2.0,4.0,2.0,4.0,3.0,5.0,1.0,3.0,2.0,4.0,2.0,4.0,3.0,5.0],
[4.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,2.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,4.0,1.0,3.0,4.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,1.0,3.0,4.0,2.0],
[2.0,3.0,4.0,6.0,7.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,6.0,1.0,2.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0],
[6.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0],
[8.0,9.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0],
[11.0,13.0,14.0,16.0,17.0,19.0,1.0,3.0,4.0,6.0,7.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,13.0,14.0,16.0,17.0,19.0,1.0],
[1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0],
[0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]])

min_occ = 2

dp = np.diff(parameterRanges2, axis=-1)
m = np.zeros((parameterRanges2.shape[0], np.max(dp) + 2), dtype=int)
arr = arr - parameterRanges2[:, :1]
ia = arr.astype(int)
idx = np.where((arr==ia) & (ia>=0) & (ia<=dp), ia, -1)
np.add.at(m, (np.arange(parameterRanges2.shape[0])[:, None], idx), 1)
res = (m[:, :-1] >= min_occ).sum(axis=-1) == dp.ravel() + 1
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[ True  True False  True False False  True  True]
```

Comment: Ok nice, is there also a possibility to say that the numbers in the ranges should accour at least 2 times or 3 times?

Comment: @Varlor Should be possible using `np.add.at` I'll try.

Comment: TIL `np.add.at`

Comment: @PaulPanzer Is it also possible to do this for float ranges? Best regards!

Comment: @Varlor depends on details and will probably cost more (O(nm log nm)). Make a new question with full example.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more efficient way just using Numpy functions, but the code below works. I can't think of a simple Numpy way to do it since we can't make a standard Numpy array of `ranges`, since all the row aren't the same length.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [2.0,4.0,3.0,5.0,1.0,3.0,2.0,4.0,2.0,4.0,3.0,5.0,1.0,3.0,2.0,4.0,2.0,4.0,3.0,5.0],
    [4.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,2.0,4.0,5.0,1.0,2.0,4.0,1.0,3.0,4.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,1.0,3.0,4.0,2.0],
    [2.0,3.0,4.0,6.0,7.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,6.0,1.0,2.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0],
    [6.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0],
    [8.0,9.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0],
    [11.0,13.0,14.0,16.0,17.0,19.0,1.0,3.0,4.0,6.0,7.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,13.0,14.0,16.0,17.0,19.0,1.0],
    [1.0,1.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,2.0],
    [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0]
])

parameterRanges2 = [(1,5),(1,5),(1,7),(1,7),(0,10),(1,20),(1,3),(0,1)]
ranges = [np.arange(u, v+1, dtype='float64') for u, v in parameterRanges2]

print([np.all(np.isin(u,v)) for u, v in zip(ranges, arr)])
```

**output**

```
[True, True, True, True, False, False, True, True]
```

Comment: Ok nice, is there also a possibility to say that the numbers in the ranges should accour at least 2 times or 3 times?